# $group by alternative when undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents that I want to group by a field unless it does not exist, then I want to group by a second field instead.

As an example consider these 4 documents:

```
{
    prop1: 'anything',
    prop2: 1
},
{
    prop1: 'anything',
    prop2: 2
},
{
    prop1: 'something'
},
{
    prop1: 'something else'
}
```

When I group by 'prop2' I will get 3 grouped results. One for:

> prop2 == 1 and
>
> prop2 == 2 and
>
> prop2 == undefined

But I want to get 4 results. One for:

> prop2 == 1 and
>
> prop2 == 2 and
>
> prop1 == 'something' and
>
> prop1 == 'something else'

Is this even possible? Is it a very complex query? Am I better off filling the missing field so it can be grouped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) conditional aggregation operator in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) stage.

```
db.coll.aggregate([ 
    { "$group": { "_id": { "$ifNull": [ "$prop1", "$prop2" ] } } }
])
```

The `$ifNull` operator return the value of the second expression if first  expression evaluates to a null value, or if the field is missing. And that is what you want here.

---

You may want to add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to your pipeline but that is will be redundant and cause a drop of performance in your application.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`$ifNull`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator in [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage before grouping as follows

```
db.cullection.aggregate(
  { $project: { "groupVal": { $ifNull: [ '$prop2', '$prop1' ] } } }, 
  { $group: { "_id": "$groupVal" } }
);
```

For each document it will set the value `groupVal` according to which it should be grouped in the next `$group` stage. So, for documents where `prop2` field is defined, the value from `prop2` will be selected, otherwise the value from `prop1`.

Comment: It is probably due to my lack of knowledge about mongodb and its queries. But doing this in the $project stage would set an accumulator in the group stage (like `prop1: { $first: '$prop1' }`) to `null` in the results somehow.

Comment: Yes, the solution with only one `$group` stage is definitely better! I didn't notice that `$ifNull` operator could be used in `$group` stage as well as in `$project` stage. You can use [**`$$ROOT`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) operator at `$project` stage to pass the whole document without `null` values to the `$group` stage.